# Missing values imputation in python

Tags: python, pandas, scikit-learn, data-science

After applying `Imputer.fit_transform()` on my dataset I am losing the column names on the transformed data frame. Is there any way to impute it without losing column names??

Comment: Hello and welcome to SO. Please take some time to read the help page, especially the sections named ["What topics can I ask about here?"](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) and ["What types of questions should I avoid asking?"](http://stackoverflow.com/help/dont-ask). And more importantly, please read the [Stack Overflow question checklist](http://m...content-available-to-author-only...e.com/q/156810/204922). You might also want to learn about [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable Examples](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve). Format your question probably and show us your work so far.

Comment: Just use the columns from your original dataframe to wrap over new returned one.

Comment: Yeah sklearn should get more integrated with pandas..but as is, they are independent from each other.. but Viveks Solution is fine.

Comment: Thank you vivek. That worked. I was looking for an easier way to do it. Thanks anyways

Answer (score 4):

As I said in the comment to the question, just replace (re-assign) the values in the dataframe with the data returned from the Imputer.

Lets say this is your dataframe:

```
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd

df = pd.DataFrame(data=[[1,2,3], 
                        [3,4,4],
                        [3,5,np.nan], 
                        [6,7,8],
                        [3,np.nan,1]],
                  columns=['A', 'B', 'C'])
```

Current `df`:

```
   A    B    C
0  1  2.0  3.0
1  3  4.0  4.0
2  3  5.0  NaN
3  6  7.0  8.0
4  3  NaN  1.0
```

If you are sending whole the `df` to Imputer, just use this:

```
df[df.columns] = Imputer().fit_transform(df)
```

If you are sending only some columns, then use those columns only to assign the results:

```
columns_to_impute = ['B', 'C']
df[columns_to_impute] = Imputer().fit_transform(df[columns_to_impute])
```

Output:

```
     A    B    C
0  1.0  2.0  3.0
1  3.0  4.0  4.0
2  3.0  5.0  4.0
3  6.0  7.0  8.0
4  3.0  4.5  1.0
```

Answer (score 0):

To up to date @Vivek's answer:

**import sklearn.preprocessing from Imputer was deprecated in scikit-learn v0.20.4 and is now completely removed in v0.22.2.**

Use no the simpleImputer (refer to the documentation [here](https://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.impute.SimpleImputer.html)):

```
from sklearn.impute import SimpleImputer
import numpy as np

imp_mean = SimpleImputer(missing_values=np.nan, strategy='mean')
```